# Not able to save values into database using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am a beginner and wanted the insert the values into the database from a custom template page but the values are not stored.

This is my Edited code and added the full template code, am not find why it is not working, any solution for this

```
<?php /* Template Name: Contact */ ?>
<?php
function contact_form() {

$name   = $_POST['name'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$comment  = $_POST['comment'];

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_contact";
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
    'name' => $name, 
    'email' => $email,
    'subject' => $subject,
    'comment' => $comment
),array(
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s')
);
}

if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) contact_form();
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container" id="contact">
<div class="row">
    <h2>Contact us</h2>
    <p>Lets get in touch and talk about your and our next project.</p><br>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required name="email">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" required name="subject">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Comment" required name="comment">
        <button name="submit" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> SEND MESSAGE
        </button>
    </form>
    </div>

</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: provide full template code.

Answer (score 0):

change table name from,

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_contact";
```

to,

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "contact";
```

Comment: can you print query by $wpdb->last_query after insert query, to see what exactly in your query?

Comment: then he need to define savequeries to true -

Answer (score 0):

You should not use core PHP code here because WordPress already made it very easy to make anything like a contact form.

You should use https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ plugin. 
It will be very easy for you without mugging in the code for this small work.

check this doc https://contactform7.com/docs/

Comment: whenever i click on the submit button, it automatically takes to the index page..I dont understand why..am not getting errors..table name is wp_contact

Comment: what is your table name ?

Comment: why you using this form why not you use 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ this plugin

Comment: This is PHP way. You should avoid core PHP use in Wordpress.
Wordpress already made everything much easier.

Comment: i am a beginner..i dont know the details, just found it from a tutorial

Comment: Use https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ plugin 
Its will be very easy for you 
without creating anything.

just check contact form video and done